# Windows 8 local storage

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, data-storage

I have searched around a lot but have not found much of anything in regards to local storage for Windows 8 metro apps. Does anyone know of any easy way to create a local storage DB with basic `save()` and `load()` functions?
All I need is to bind some `XAML` to some data (titles, descriptions etc). I have made windows phone 7 apps before using Isolatedstoragesystem but obviously it is different for windows 8... documentation didn't help much either >.< Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at some of these [links](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+8+metro+local+storage+c%23&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=windows+8+metro+local+storage+c%23&sc=0-30&sp=-1&sk=) see if they help

Comment: Yeah, there all purple from being clicked on :/

Comment: Take a look at this Codeplex project http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/

Comment: you can always use an external db. atm i'm creating windows store app that connects via api with db in azure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a spectrum of options available to you, and there are code samples you should check out - specifically the [Application Data Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2) at the [Windows Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com)

You could use app file storage, local data (dictionary stored on device), roaming data (dictionary stored in the cloud) - all of which are accessible via [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.current.aspx).  For example,

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["FirstName"] = "Joe"
```

Beyond that you could pull in SQLite for relational type storage managed in-process.

Comment: Thanks! This will work for now, SQLite should be a good direction for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Lex.Db seems to be pretty nice on a cursory inspection. I just tested it in a win rt project. It is available on nuget.
https://github.com/demigor/lex.db